# which system should I choose to make it easier to transfer it to a cluster later?

Tags: redis, cluster-analysis, redis-cluster, keydb

we have a small project, and we want to start using a non-clustered version of either keydb or redis. I've read a lot of reviews. I would like to hear more. Which system will be easier to turn into a cluster in the future, and maybe transfer to kubernetes?

Comment: Both redis and keydb have established helm charts for deployment to kubernetes, so either work. What reservations/concerns do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding scaling/simplicity, I would point out both Redis and KeyDB are able to turn into sharded clusters, or add replica nodes, KeyDB also offers active replication (some limits, but avoids sentinel). Both are also compatible with RESP protocol so can use any Redis client.

A few points relevant to both KeyDB and Redis when trying to simplify scaling in the future (ie. moving to a sharded data set):

- Ensure you use a client that is compatible with cluster-mode enabled as not all are
- Be careful of how you use transactions. If you rely heavily on transactions that hit multiple keys, you may need to rethink this when spreading data across multiple shards.
- The point above also applies to certain commands that can hit multiple shards such as SCAN, KEYS, batch requests (ie. MGET), SUNION, etc. Planning how you structure your data may make this easier when you decide to scale up.